# Encrypt WCF message password

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, security

A third party in charge of developing Java based webservice came back to us with requirement that message header needs to look like this:

```
<soapenv:Header>
 <wsse:Security>
     <xenc:ReferenceList>
        <xenc:DataReference URI="#EncDataId-1"/>
     </xenc:ReferenceList>
     <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>[snip]</wsse:Username>
        <xenc:EncryptedData Id="EncDataId-1" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
           <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
           <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
              <ds:KeyName>[snip]</ds:KeyName>
           </ds:KeyInfo>
           <xenc:CipherData>
              <xenc:CipherValue>[snip]</xenc:CipherValue>
           </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Given my very surfacish understanding of this security voodoo magic I am having trouble figuring out how configure my client to produce such header. Right now my code looks like this:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "[snip]";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "[snip]";
```

and the header:

```
<s:Header>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-e906a1ca-aa63-474c-b4ac-cf9b90ab2435-1">
            <o:Username>[snip]</o:Username>
            <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">[snip]</o:Password>
        </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
</s:Header>
```

and binding:

```
<binding name="SMSSoap11">
    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
</binding>
```

Comment: Can you post what your current SOAP envelope looks like? You can use a tool like Fiddler to catch it.

Comment: And how closely do they need it to their format, because the default formatting is quite a bit different (tag names are different, for example). If you need their exact tag names, then you're going to need to create your own message formatter. Here's an article that describes how: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx

Comment: If they have some flexibility in their requirements, then you might not have to go that far, but my gut instinct says that's what you're going to need to do.

Comment: @Pete I've updated my question with my current header. I sort of had a feeling this will require a custom solution, but maybe then I can just push back at them to bring back old security header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF will not produce this output for you. You will have to write [your own token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731872.aspx) for this and maybe even more. WCF supports only username token with plain password out-of-the-box and your code example even doesn't look like any part of username token specification. If the goal is to use encrypted password with WS-Security then the security header seems incomplete.

You should ask Java developers what are security requirements in terms of WS-SecurityPolicy?

Comment: I had a feeling this is the case, but could not support it myself. Your answer gave me confidence to push back on this requirement.